# how to create paint bucket tool on canvas using fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I want to create a paint bucket tool
I am using  Fabric javascript library.

I am using canvas.getActiveObject().set("fill","rgb(0,0,0)");. it works on the default shapes. but does not fill shapes drawn using pencil tool

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you should go through tutorial and examples given on site. and then if you find any difficult you should write here

Comment: I am using canvas.getActiveObject().set("fill","rgb(0,0,0)");. it works on the default shapes. but does not fill shapes drawn using pencil tool

Comment: this should be in your question. Post what you have tried, if possible post full code so someone can give you desire answer